# Use of Domain Objects in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-data, spring-integration

I have say domain objects A,B,C,D etc.

I want to use domain Object A through out my flow. Object A has Object B,C,D etc as class variables with setter and getter.

I have spring integration flow like.

```
public Class A
{

    private B b;

    private C c;

    private D d;

    //setter and getter

}
```

Pick B Object from `queue-->create Object A` and `set B` and pass A as payload to next step--> get Object C from database (jpa) and set in Same Object A and pass to next step--> so on so at last step I should have object A having values of Object B,C,D etc.

Please suggest how to configure this in spring integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [content enricher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#content-enricher) which is a specialized gateway that allows you to populate attributes of the payload with the results of running a sub-flow.